# Schengen visa under appeal, when can I reapply?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, tourist-visas, schengen-visas

Our Schengen visa to France was refused on the basis of, what I understand now, some basic errors with the documentation provided. We appealed that decision, but in retrospect I do think it unlikely that the appeal will be accepted (failure to provide exact itinerary as it wasn't in required documentation, and a hotel booking lapsing as we didn't make the non refundable payment). I do feel we can make a much better application now. My question is, that as it has been 10 days since we submitted the appeal, how much longer do I wait before filing a fresh application? If I re-apply, would the fact that I have already appealed an earlier decision negatively impact my new application?

Comment: Are you sure it was just some basic errors, and not a fundamental question of fitting the profile of a typical tourist (income, ties to homeland, ...)?

Comment: Yes. We're a double income family, with properties, employment and bi-annual trips to various parts of the world. While returning our documents, the individual asked us whether any of our hotel bookings had been cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [French Ministry for Europe and Foreign Affairs](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/faq-visas)

> If your visa is refused, you may also submit a new visa application immediately and at any time.
>
> You may appeal against a decision to refuse you a visa by applying to the Commission de recours contre les décisions de refus de visa d’entrée en France (Board of Appeals against decisions to refuse an entry visa to France) within 2 months of the date of notification of the refusal.

As you note, before re-applying, you would want to remedy any issues raised in the refusal, making changes and improvements as appropriate.